# What is difference between found and required in following errors

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, kafka-streams-scala

While working on Scala Kafka `KeyValueMapper` implementation I am getting following error. I am not sure what exactly is the difference.
Thanks for your help.

Code:

1. I created a `KTable` from topic.

   ```
   val creducer: Reducer[java.lang.Long] =
     (v1, v2) => if (v1 > v2) v1 else v2

   val deduplicationWindow = TimeWindows
     .of(60000L * 10)
     .advanceBy(60000L)
     .until(60000L * 10)

   val ktwindow: KTable[Windowed[String], java.lang.Long] =
     ipandTime
       .groupByKey(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long())
       .reduce(creducer, deduplicationWindow, "ktwindow-query")
   ```
2. I am getting error while using selectKey method when I try to create stream with key of `Windowed[String]`. Similar implementation in java works fine.

   ```
   val fStream = ktwindow
     .toStream()
     .selectKey(
       new KeyValueMapper[Windowed[String],
                          java.lang.Long,
                          KeyValue[String, java.lang.Long]] {
         override def apply(
             key: Windowed[String],
             value: java.lang.Long): KeyValue[String, java.lang.Long] = {
           new KeyValue(key.key(), value)
         }
       }
     )
   ```

```
[error]  found   : org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper[org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed[String],Long,org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue[String,Long]]

[error]  required: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper[_ >: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed[String], _ >: Long, _ <: KR]
```

Comment: Can you please share the code snippet and context to understand the question better ?

Comment: I have edited the question with code snippet.

Comment: Looks like a common issue with type inference when using Java's call-site generics. Try attaching the explicit type parameters to `.groupByKey[Param1,...,ParamN](...)` and `.reduce[Param1, ..., ParamM](...)`, if the types actually do match, the errors will go away.

Comment: Hi @AndreyTyukin not sure I am doing it correctly. for example, api of groupByKey is  
`KGroupedStream<K,V> groupByKey(Serde<K> keySerde,
                             Serde<V> valSerde)`
Then what would be Param1, Param2 becomes for my code ?
`ipandTime
    .groupByKey[Param1, Param2 ](Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `ipandTime` was nowhere to find, so I've replaced it by a `???`, but that doesn't have anything to do with the actual problem.

As I said, if type inference for Java use-site wildcards fails, then simply add explicit type arguments. This here compiles for Kafka 1.1.0:

```
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream._
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization._
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue


object Q49594920 {

      val creducer: Reducer[java.lang.Long] =
      (v1, v2) => if (v1 > v2) v1 else v2

    val deduplicationWindow = TimeWindows
      .of(60000L * 10)
      .advanceBy(60000L)
      .until(60000L * 10)

    val ktwindow: KTable[Windowed[String], java.lang.Long] = ???
      // ipandTime // What's that? It's not defined anywhere!
      //   .groupByKey(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long())
      //   .reduce(creducer, deduplicationWindow, "ktwindow-query")

    val fStream = ktwindow
      .toStream()
      .selectKey[KeyValue[String, java.lang.Long]](
        new KeyValueMapper[Windowed[String],
                           java.lang.Long,
                           KeyValue[String, java.lang.Long]] {
          override def apply(
              key: Windowed[String],
              value: java.lang.Long): KeyValue[String, java.lang.Long] = {
            new KeyValue(key.key(), value)
          }
        }
      )
}
```

The `selectKey` method wanted a generic type argument `KR`, so I just gave the concrete type `KeyValue[String, java.lang.Long]` to it, then it just worked.